# Why Qt calculator example does not compile?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to compile [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-calculator-example.html) example. But linker shows me 3 errors - don't know why because I copied whole project. I paste here only one error, since 2 others are similar. How can I repair this? EDIT: it shows me also that there is no calculator.obj file

> **calculator.obj:-1**: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Button::Button(class QString const &,class QWidget *)" (??0Button@@QEAA@AEBVQString@@PEAVQWidget@@@Z) referenced in function "private: class Button * __cdecl Calculator::createButton(class QString const &,char const *)" (?createButton@Calculator@@AEAAPEAVButton@@AEBVQString@@PEBD@Z)

Comment: How do you compile it? using some IDE? which version of QT do you have?

Comment: using qt creator MSVC2015_64

Comment: In Linux compiles successfully. Using _Qt Creator 4.2.0 (4.2.0)_ and _Qt 5.7.1 (GCC 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10), 64 bit)_.

Comment: It compiles fine in Windows too, using _MSVC2013 64 bit_ and _MinGW 32 bit_.